# How to write new input file after modify flopy package?

Tags: flopy

I try to load-if exists, update and write new input files in flopy. I try many things but I can't. Here is my code:

```
rchFile = os.path.join(modflowModel.model_ws, "hydrogeology.rch")

info = modflowModel.get_nrow_ncol_nlay_nper()
if "RCH" in modflowModel.get_package_list():
    rchObject = ModflowRch.load(rchFile, modflowModel)
    rchData = rchObject.rech
else:
    rchData = dict()
    for ts in range(info[3]):
        rchData[ts] = np.zeros((info[0], info[1]))

for feat in iterator:
    for ts in range(info[3]):
        currValue = "random value"
        rchData[ts][feat["row"]-1, feat["column"]-1] = currValue

rchObject = ModflowRch(modflowModel, nrchop=3, ipakcb=None, rech=rchData, irch=0, extension='rch', unitnumber=None, filenames="hydrogeology.rch")

rchPath = os.path.join(modflowModel.model_ws, 'rch.shp')
rchObject.export(f=rchPath)
# rchObject.write_file()
# modflowModel.add_package(rchObject)
modflowModel.write_input()
```

`modflowModel` is and `flopy.modflow.Modflow` object. Comments at the end of the codes are lines that I try to write updated new inputs but does not work.

Answer (score 2):

What error(s) are you getting exactly when you say it doesnt work?  I routinely modify forcing packages with flopy like this:

```
m = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load()
for kper in range(m.nper):
    arr = m.rch.rech[kper].array
    arr *= 0.8 # or something
    m.rch.rech[kper] = arr
```

Comment: When I apply my script it does not create *.rch file or not updating existing file. I can not see the package in *.nam file, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. `modflowModel.write_input()` works very well. Problem occures while loading model object `Modflow.load(...)`. Now I load model whereever I need. Because if I load it another py etc., there might me `model_ws` confusion.